# C# how to not serialize an already serialized string with Content

Tags: c#, serialization

So I have built an REST API that in itself also consumes another API. Now I could just call the other api, create objects from that call and then make a new request and send it on it's way but that would use up a bit of performance.

I tried just sending the second request again but the problem is that Content serializes it again so I get alot of backslashes. This is my code that does this:

```
   [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllDevices()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request = new RestRequest("devices", Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.Content);//response.Content get's serialized again.
    }
```

As I said, I could deserialized the first call and then just put that in Content, but it feels unnecessary.

Comment: If the first request returns string as the response then stick it in the stringcontent and then return that stringco tent from ur service .

Comment: But then my API just returns a string not a proper request?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It seems ur service is just a thin wrapper on top of existing service which just passes the response along . In just case better to return it as is, i.e if you get Json back from first service just wrap and return that string .

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The problem is that if I just return the response.Content as a string I get alot of backslahes. I also tried returning the whole response object, but that gives a string of all the methods returnvalue in the object. If I print the response.Content to the console window it is correct but the moment I call the api there are alot of backslashes everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it, remember to set the content-type explicitly to application/json if needed:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("test")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Test()
    {
        const string json = "{ \"test\": 123 }";  // from RestClient
        var res = Request.CreateResponse();
        res.Content = new StringContent(json);
        res.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
        return res;
    }
```